# How to style text in a string array?

Tags: android, arrays, coding-style

I have a string array and was trying to style certain parts of the text with tags like < b>, < i>, ... but it doesn't work.
The array looks like this:

```
<resources>
    <array name="hour1">                             
            <item>blabla\n<b>blabla</b></item>
</array>
```

The text is displayed in the textview like this:

```
tTitel.setText(Html.fromHtml(Text[ii]));
```

I tried it without Html.fromHtml too but this had no effect. The styling tags do work if i use them directly in the code, like:

```
tTitel.setText(Html.fromHtml("blabla<b>blabla</b>");
```

Any ideas how to style the text in an array??

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: What exactly is `Text[ii]` in the above line? Have you tried accessing it directly via `R.java`?

Comment: It's an array that contains one item of the string array "hour1". I need that because I split the text and then do different things with it based on what pattern made it split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape your HTML tags when they are included in an XML resource document. Instead of:

```
<b>
```

use:

```
&lt;b&gt;
```

At least, that works for ordinary string resources. I assume it works for string arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly fine!
Using < b> in ordinary string resources without escaping it works for me, too. That's why I hadn't thought of that.
Thanks again!

Comment: Really? That's interesting. The last time I tried embedding un-escaped HTML in string resources, it failed. I haven't tried in over a year, though, so perhaps that was fixed and the fix didn't ripple through to string-array resources.